Why does Pycharm lose all Run/Debug configurations [on rare occasions]?
The run/debug configurations are crucial for my work.  It happens maybe once in several months that they all disappear.  I'm not sure what triggers this to happen and if there were any way to recover them.  Any pointers?

Are your run configurations saved? If they aren't, they should be faded out.

I had maybe 15 or 20 saved configurations and about a dozen unsaved ones .

Saved configurations should be exported to the .idea subdirectory, so the lost ones are probably all unsaved. The simple solution is to save them. Does that answer the question?

Hi @InSync I mentioned in prior comment that 15 or 20 were saved. Something got broken in Pycharm, I am wondering if  a workaround were known.

If the run configs aren't physically saved on the disc/repository they're gone... I'm not aware of any case (say if you opened the IDE with another user account) where the run configs would be lost because by default they'll be project specific and saved inside the project's folder. Could it be you saved the entire project to a new directory and for some reason the run configs weren't migrated during the saving process? Anyway, developing locally what you describe has never happened to me, I'm guessing you manage your projects in some way that's different from how I do it.

@bad_coder   I think you nailed it, I just realized that yes I had moved the directory. If you wish to get some points please make an answer
